# How to find the fprintf() actual error?

Tags: c++, c, file, file-io

In my program `fprintf()` returns -1, which indicates an error. How can I find out what actual error was?

Comment: It is on the 36th character of line 42.

Comment: Just to explain the ironic (and funny) answer of @AProgrammer: when you ask a question that is related to your code, it is actually **way more** efficient to post the actual code with your question. We clearly cannot guess what you typed.

Comment: @ereOn: It's not ironic. The TRUE answer to what IS the ACTUAL error is 42 indeed. I'm still scratching my head trying to get what 36 stands for :)

Comment: 36 is the biggest square smaller than 42 ;-)

Comment: @AProgrammer: that makes sense now. cheers! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

...
rc = fprintf(...)
if (rc < 0) 
    printf("errno=%d, err_msg=\"%s\"\n", errno,strerror(errno))
```

Comment: You should not declare `errno` yourself, just include `<errno.h>`; it might be a macro, not a variable.

Comment: point taken. libc os dependent. I think on older linux libcs you'd have to declare it extern tho. corrected.

Comment: Err, adirau, that's even _worse._ `#ifndef` will only work for preprocessor macros, not variables. You're better off ditching that whole `#ifdef` block since ISO mandates that `errno.h` defines an `errno` "variable". I fixed it up for you, hope you don't mind.

Comment: but errno is a preprocessor macro, at least on unix and linux :)

Comment: i used the ifdefs thinking of the old errno libc linux implemenation where errno is(/was?) exactly an  int; so if errno isn't a cpp macro then it should be declared extern but those are oldtimes you are right

Comment: Per the standard, you **must** include `errno.h` to get errno and **must not** declare it yourself.

Comment: `errno` might be something like `#define errno (*__get_thread_local_errno_ptr())`, but it also might just be `extern int errno;`. You don't know. Always use `errno.h`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the value of `errno`. Most library functions will set it to the specific error code and you can either look it up in `errno.h` or use `perror` or `strerror` to get a user-readable version.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main (void) {
    FILE *fh = fopen ("junk", "w");
    if (fh != NULL) {
        if (fprintf (fh, "%s", "hello") < 0)
            fprintf (stderr, "err=%d: %s\n", errno, strerror (errno));
        fclose (fh);
    }
    return 0;
}
```